Recuperar campos de un listado y editarlos
Tengo los siguientes archivos:
formulario.php
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function ($clase) {
    include '../clases/' . $clase . '.php';
});

// Recuperamos la información de la sesión
session_start();

// Y comprobamos que el usuario se haya autentificado
if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    die("Error - debe <a href='login.php'>identificarse</a>.<br />");
}

// Comprobamos si se quiere añadir un producto a la cesta
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    $cesta->newArticulo($_POST['cod']);
    $cesta->saveCesta();
}

// Obtenemos los datos necesarios
$usuario = Usuario::implicito();
$usuario->unserialize($_SESSION['usuario']);
$productos = DB::getProductosTabla();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Formulario</title>
    <link href="../css/tienda.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="contenedor">
        <div id="encabezado">
            <h1>GESTIÓN DE PRODUCTOS</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="formularioBotones">
            <form action="formInsertProducto.php" method="post">
                <!--Botón para insertar producto-->
                <input type="submit" name="insertaP" value="Insertar Producto" />
            </form>

            <form action="formBuscarProducto.php" method="post">
                <!--Botón para buscar producto-->
                <input type="submit" name="buscarP" value="Buscar Producto" />
            </form>

            <form action="fin.php" method="post">
                <!--Botón para finalizar-->
                <input type="submit" name="finalizar" value="Finalizar" />
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="cesta">
            <table>
                <thead class="cabeceraTabla">
                    <th>CÓDIGO</th>
                    <th>NOMBRE</th>
                    <th>NOMBRE CORTO</th>
                    <th class="descripcion">DESCRIPCIÓN</th>
                    <th>PVP</th>
                    <th>FAMILIA</th>
                    <th>ACCIÓN</th>
                </thead>


                <?php foreach ($productos as $producto) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $producto->getCodigo(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $producto->getNombre(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $producto->getNombreCorto(); ?></td>
                        <td class="descripcion"><?php echo $producto->getDescripcion(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $producto->getPVP(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $producto->getFamilia(); ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <form action="editarProducto.php" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="cod_producto" value="<?php echo $producto->getCodigo(); ?>" />

                                <!--Botones para insertar productos-->
                                <input type="submit" name="editar" value="Editar" />
                            </form>
                            <form action="" method="post">
                                <input type="submit" name="eliminar" value="Eliminar" />
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </table>
            <br class="divisor" />
            <div id="pie">
                <form action='logoff.php' method='post'>
                    <!-- Aparece el nombre y los apellidos del usuario -->
                    <input type="submit" name="desconectar" value="Desconectar usuario <?= $usuario->getNombre() ?> <?= $usuario->getApellidos() ?>" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>

</html>

Y el archivo editarFormulario.php
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($clase) {
    include '../clases/' . $clase . '.php';
});

// Recuperamos la información de la sesión
session_start();

// Y comprobamos que el usuario se haya autentificado
if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    die("Error - debe <a href='login.php'>identificarse</a>.<br />");
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Editar producto</title>
    <link href="../css/tienda.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="contenedor">

        <div id="encabezado">
            <h1>Modificación producto: - </h1>
        </div>

        <div id="contenido">
            <h2>Producto a modificar:</h2>
            <form action="actualizar.php" method="post" id="producto">

                <!--Código-->
                <label for="cod_producto">Código: </label>
                <input type="text" name="cod_producto" value=" " />
                <br><br>

                <!--Nombre-->
                <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" class="nombre">
                <br><br>

                <!--Nombre corto-->
                <label for="nombre_corto">Nombre corto:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre_corto" class="nombre" value="">
                <br><br>

                <!--Descripción-->
                <label for="descripcion">Descripción:</label>
                <textarea id="descripcion" name="descripcion" rows="15" cols="120">

                    </textarea>
                <br><br>

                <!--PVP-->
                <label for="PVP">PVP:</label>
                <input type="text" name="PVP" value="">
                <br><br>

                <!--Familia-->
                <label for="cod_familia">Familia:</label>
                <select id="cod_familia" name="cod_familia" required>
                    <option selected disabled>Seleccione una familia</option>
                    <?php
                    $familias = DB::getFamilias(); // Obtener familias desde la base de datos una sola vez
                    if (!empty($familias)) {
                        // Utilizar un array para almacenar las familias ya impresas
                        $familias_impresas = array();
                        foreach ($familias as $familia) {
                            // Verificar si la familia ya ha sido impresa
                            if (!in_array($familia, $familias_impresas)) {
                    ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $familia; ?>"><?php echo $familia; ?></option>
                    <?php
                                // Agregar la familia actual al array de familias impresas
                                $familias_impresas[] = $familia;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="actualizar" value="Aceptar" />
                <input type="submit" name="cancelar" value="Cancelar" />

            </form>
            <form id='volver' action='formulario.php' method='post'>
                <input type='submit' value='Volver' name='volver' />
            </form>
        </div>


    </div>

</body>

</html>

No soy capaz de recuperar los campos del formulario para poder realizar la siguiente pregunta: El botón “Editar” asociado a cada producto, mostrará un formulario con los campos y valores
del producto asociado al botón permitiendo la modificación de todos los campos a excepción del código que es PK. Para la familia mostrará una lista desplegable con todas las familias permitiendo seleccionar una de ellas para que el usuario no tenga que marcar el código de la
familia.
Si alguien pudiera orientarme. Gracias!

Hola. Describe el problema. Por ejemplo: le doy a Editar y no sale nada, o sale tal error, o no hace nada, etc. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta y agrega cualquier error que veas.

Suponiendo que donde has puesto Y el archivo editarFormulario.php sea un error y quieras decir Y el archivo editarProducto.php, mirando ese archivo no se aprecia que uses para nada el valor de la variable pasada en el formulario cod_producto, cuando lo lógico seria aprovechar ese valor para consultar en la base de datos el resto de campos y rellenar los campos de edición.  Inténtalo y nos cuentas que has conseguido.
